# How do I teleport a player when a mob gets close?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make it when a zombie comes within 1 block of me I get teleported somewhere. I want to do this with 1.16.2 command blocks.

I don't know how to do this yet, but I only need the command, not the explanation.

Comment: Hey, and thanks for your question! Unlike other forums, we're not the best place to ask if you need help without trying something before you post. *([why?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask))* Feel free to [search](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search) our site for previous questions that may be helpful, and if you are on your way and encounter a specific issue, you're more than welcome to ask here!

Comment: I already searched everywhere, there's no question like this one

Comment: Where do you want the player to be teleported?

Comment: Just to some coordinates

Comment: Remember that you can always upvote and accept my answer if you think it suits you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not provide details to where you are going to be teleported, I will provide some examples.

Baseline command:

```
/execute as @a at @s if entity @s[distance=0..1, type=zombie] run tp @s x y z
```

Assume your "safe house" is at coordinates `0 64 0`. Replace `x y z` with `0 64 0`, so the player will be teleported to `0 64 0` if a zombie gets too close to a player.

You can also use tilde and caret notation. More information about that can be found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Local_coordinates:_Caret_notation). To teleport the player 10 blocks forward, use `^ ^ ^10` instead of `x y z`.

I hope this helps. Comment down below if there are any issues with this solution.